# How to change the font size of only the console panel in RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

I have found other posts showing how to change the font size of only the Help panel, and I know how to Zoom In and Out via keyboard shortcuts, or by using the long way.

I also know that you can change the font size of the editor in the Appearances option.

However, I would like to reduce the font size of **only** the console panel.
I would like to keep my editor font nice and big, but the console one is mostly for checking out quick data.frames so the smaller the better.

I tried fiddling around the source code of Rstudio to no avail.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I have asked the same question at Rstudio community but nobody has answered yet community.rstudio.com/t/different-font-size-for-the-console-how/132040